# Securing file uploads inside the document root PHP

Tags: php, file-upload

After reading several threads and articles about securing file uploads I want to check if I have sufficiently secured my uploads. Please notice that I do only have limited admin rights, which makes it difficult to upload/access/manage files outside of the document root.

My uploads folder is in `/html/uploads.`

For now, I have done the following:

- I removed the public rights to read, write or execute from the uploads folder
- I removed the group rights to read, write or execute from the uploads folder
- I have inserted `accept="image/*,.doc, .docx,.pdf"` into the `<input/>` tag.
- I check on errors, the max size and the extension via

  ```
  foreach ($_FILES['files']['name'] as $f => $name) {
  if ($_FILES['files']['error'][$f] == 4) {
      $break = "yes";
      continue; // Skip file if any error found
  }
  ```

  and following with checks on max-size and extension
- The max number of files uploaded has been limited to 6 by the server
- I rename the files after being uploaded

Now since I have read lots about saving files outside of the document root and being unexperienced with uploads, I am not sure if this is enough to make the uploads of the page "safe". Is it ok like this or is it simply not possible to make it "safe" when saving it not outside the document root?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best thing you can do (if you can't do anything outside your document root) is add a `.htaccess` file to your uploads folder:

```
deny from all
```

This will prevent any access to the files over the internet, which is basically as good as having them outside the document root. This way, even if someone finds a loophole around your upload validation, they can't access the files directly online. In particular, this means they can't upload a PHP file and trick your server into executing it.

Comment: Just to be sure: If I want to create folders for each upload under `/html/uploads/` before the files are moved and the folder doesn't exist (e.g. `/html/uploads/potatoe1/`)  - does the .htaccess still work/cover the sub-folders (for `/potatoe1/`, `/potatoe2/` etc.) if I put it into the `/html/uploads/` folder?

Comment: I... actually don't know. But you can test it easily enough. If it turns out that it doesn't, you can always put a duplicate of the `.htaccess` file in each new subfolder you create.

Comment: I have tested it for `/html/uploads/` e.g. tried to call `/html/uploads/potatoe1.png` with the .htaccess inside of `/html/uploads/`. For the folder itself (`www.xxx.net/uploads/`) it worked and I received the "Forbidden" message, but if I call `www.xxx.net/uploads/potatoe1.png` the image is displayed like normal in the browser - I guess that means it's not working or is the picture safe though it can be called?

Comment: It might be that the picture was cached in your browser. Use Ctrl+F5 when viewing the picture and see if the server still sends it to you.

Comment: Ah the Ctrl+F5 check, I forget it much too often. Thanks a lot! It works and it also works for the subfolders now.